# Is there correct way to use python typing?

Tags: python-3.x, typing, pylance, type-variables

I'm trying to figure out typing in Python and I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def convert_to_iter(var: T | Iterable[T]) -> Iterable[T]:
    if not isinstance(var, Iterable):
        return (var, )
    return var
```

I am using Pylance in VScode with `typeCheckingMode: "strict"` and am getting the error on the last line of the code:

`Return type, "Iterable[Unknown]* | Iterable[T@convert_to_list]", is partially unknown` `Pylance(reportUnknownVariableType)`

Can someone please explain why this is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/2539) about such question.
So, this behavior can be explained by type narrowing.
One of the existing ways to eliminate this error is to use `cast` function